# Convergence of $A^t$

Tags: matrices, convergence-divergence, dynamical-systems

Consider

$$a_t = Aa_{t-1}$$

i.e.

$$a_t = A^ta_0$$

for a matrix $A$ and an intial vector $a_0$.

In wonder whether this process converges iff the process

$$b_t = Ab_{t-1}+c$$

converges, starting from the same $a_0$, and a fixed vector $c$.

We have

$$b_t = A^ta_0+\left(\sum_{s=0}^{t-1}A^s\right)c$$

Intuitively, I would say, if $a_t$ converges then also $b_t$, but I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $b_t$ can diverge even if $a_t$ converges and vice-versa.

Consider the problem for the scalar case $A = 1$, $a_0 = 1$, and $c = 1$.

Then, $a_t = A^ta_0 = 1^t \cdot 1 = 1$ for all $t$, so $a_t$ converges to $1$ as $t \to \infty$. However, $b_t = A^ta_0+\displaystyle\sum_{s = 0}^{t-1}A^sc = 1^t \cdot 1 + \sum_{s = 0}^{t-1}1^s \cdot 1 = 1+(t-1) = t$ which diverges as $t \to \infty$.

Also, consider the problem for the scalar case $A = -1$, $a_0 = 1$, $c = 2$.

Then, $a_t = A^ta_0 = (-1)^t \cdot 1 = (-1)^t$ which does not converge as $t \to \infty$. However, $b_t = A^ta_0+\displaystyle\sum_{s = 0}^{t-1}A^sc = (-1)^t \cdot 1 + \sum_{s = 0}^{t-1}(-1)^s \cdot 2 = (-1)^t + \dfrac{1-(-1)^t}{1-(-1)} \cdot 2 = 1$ for all $t$, so $b_t$ converges to $1$ as $t \to \infty$.

---

Note: In order to ensure that both $a_t$ and $b_t$ converge, you need the condition $\|A\| < 1$, i.e. all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are between $-1$ and $1$ exclusive.

Comment: Thanks! And i think now that if $b_t$ converges, then also $a_t$ (since the von-Neumann-series $b_t$ converges iff $\rho(A)<1$)

Comment: Actually, that's also false. Consider the scalar case $A = -1$, $a_0 = 1$, $c = 2$. Then we have $a_t = (-1)^t$ which does not converge, while $b_t = 1$ for all $t$, which converges to $1$.

Comment: Haha, true. Maybe I should have read your answer to the end before posting :P

Comment: Note: if $||A||<1$, then $a_t$ and $b_t$ converge, but the converse is not true for $a_t$ since $a_t$ can also converge when $||A||=1$. The von Neumann series converges iff $||A||<1$ but also $b_t$ may converge under weaker conditions, e.g. when $c$ is adequately specified.

Comment: I thank you a lot for your help @JimmyK4542. Can't upvote you though unfortunately - since I'm not a standard user.